# Want an explanation of the solution to this problem with counting numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

You are given  integers  and You are required to find the count of all the PR numbers in the range L to R  inclusively. PR number are the numbers which satisfy following  properties: -

:- No pair of adjacent digits are coprime i.e.  adjacent digits in a PR number will not be coprime to each other.

:- PR number is divisible by all the single digit prime numbers which occur as a digit in the PR number.

Comment: Dynamic Programming is the suggested approach to solve this. But i want to know how?.

Comment: This is known as digit-DP, you can read about it here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digit-dp-introduction/

Comment: @Photon: Thanks. Will check surely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many PR numbers exist in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343003/how-many-pr-numbers-exist-in-a-given-range)

Comment: It would be good to know the size of the range, so as to give you a "feasible" approach.