# How to maximize the weight of a tree by removing subtrees

Tags: binary-tree, subtree

There is a rooted tree with N nodes (numbered 1 through N); node '1' is the root. Each node has a value; let's denote the value of node i by A(i).

The following operation(s) can be performed any number of times (including zero):

1.choose any node which still exists in the tree and remove the whole sub- tree  of this node including itself.

2.Let's define the profit as the sum of values of all nodes which currently exist in the tree minus X⋅k, where k denotes the number of times this operation was performed. Find the maximum possible profit.

How can we calculate 'k' value here?(means no. of time node is deleted to give optimum profit)

Example:-

```
3(number of nodes,N) ,

5(X)

1 -5 -10 (Values of corresponding nodes)

(edge(s) from 'x'->'y')

1 2

2 3

Output: -4

We remove the sub-tree of node : 2'.

Now,value of our tree is: 1.

Finals answer:- 1-(x)*k,
(k=1); as we have performed the operation of removing the sub-tree only '1' time 
:  1-(5)*1= -4.
```

**NOTE:it's not given that tree should be binary it can be a general tree too.**

Comment: In your example, is it possible that "Output:- -4" should be "Output:- -14"? Also, avoid using ":-", the hyphen makes it very confusing with the minus sign.

Comment: You've tagged this binary-tree, but nothing in the problem description actually says the tree is binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a straightforward recursive algorithm for this. The most profitable pruning you can perform on a tree is either to perform the most profitable pruning on all of its direct subtrees, or to just prune away the whole tree. This can be translated directly to code.

Assuming the tree has been processed into a data structure where every node has a `value` attribute representing the node's value and a `children` attribute storing a list of the node's child nodes, the following Python function would compute the max profit:

```
def max_profit(node):
    return max(
        -X,
        node.value + sum(map(max_profit, node.children)))
```

with the two options in the `max` call representing the choice to either prune the whole tree away at the root, or to keep the root and process the subtrees.

Comment: can you write the code in a bit more detailed manner so I can understand?

Comment: @user2357112 I agree that your solution is much simpler, without having to actually prune the tree to know the maximum profit.

Comment: @Gilles-Philippe Paillé  I am new to trees, can you explain his solution to me? Thanks :-)

Comment: what is the base condition of our function? What if a node does not have anymore children, what will it do now ?

Comment: @Firexsecred: Then the `map` iterates over 0 children and makes 0 recursive calls, and the `sum` sums 0 numbers and produces 0.

Comment: @user2357112 the problem is I dk python, so got confused for the meaning of map, what will be the time complexity of this algorithm , say for 'n' nodes? Thanks:-)

Comment: thanks, I've understood everything, just want to clear up the time complexity thing :-)

Comment: Linear time in the number of nodes.

Comment: Nice idea. But do keep in mind that the tree has undirected edges. So use a visited array while traversing through!

Comment: @user2357112 any ideas on this tree problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549158/how-to-count-the-number-of-intersections

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to parse the tree, and see which subtree could be removed such that the profit will increase compared to its initial state. Do this analysis for every node before removing anything. Then, remove the subtrees that increases the most the profit. We can do it in two passes:

1) Doing a depth-first traversal of the tree (leaves first, then slowly going back towards the root), calculate the profit gain of each node as the `G(i)=-A(i)+G(j)+G(k)+...`, where `i` is the current node, and `j,k,...` are the children. In other words, the profit gain is the added value if we remove the current node.

During the same traversal, also compute the maximum profit gain of the node and its children. This will tell us if it is more profitable to remove a node or if it is more profitable to remove a subtree of this node. We compute the maximum profit gain as `M(i) = max(G(i),M(j),M(k),...)`, where `i,j,k,...` are defined as above. If a child does not exist, just remove it from the `max` equation.

2) Doing a breadth-first traversal of the tree, we remove a node `i` (and its subtree) if `G(i) == M(i)` and `G(i) >= X`.

```py
def compute_gain(node):
    map(compute_gain, node.children)
    node.gain = -node.value + sum([c.gain for c in node.children])
    node.max_gain = max(node.gain, max([c.max_gain for c in node.children]))

def prune_tree(node):
    if node.gain >= X and node.max_gain == node.gain:
        k += 1
        return False
    node.children = [c for c in node.children if prune_tree(c) == True]
```

Comment: But how do we remove a subtree?,the constraints of the problem are tight and the given tree is not a binary tree.

Comment: I assumed that it was a binary tree since he used the keyword. What do you mean by "contraints are tight"? Removing a node depends on the data structure, but in general, you delete the two children first, then the node. Deleting the children will recursively destroy their own children, etc.

Comment: The solution is till unclear to me. The tree is not binary and data structure to implement such a tree is also unclear. could you please provide a better solution with data structure and traversal code.

Comment: @UjjwalRoy Since the problem was abstract without any specific language, I did not see the use of providing code. Especially for these kind of problems, I personally think it is more useful to concentrate on the idea rather that technical stuff. But if it makes things clearer, I can provide a bit of code. The solution can be easily extended to non-binary trees, I just assumed it was binary because of the tag and that nowhere it specifies that it is not binary. I will modify the solution.