# Maximize weight of a rooted tree by removing subtrees

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have a tree rooted at 1.I can remove the whole subtree of any node and this operation can be performed any no. of times.

Let's say we performed the above operation k no. of times. We need to maximize Total_weight - C*k, where C is a positive constant.

The weight of nodes can be positive as well as negative.

For eg-(1,1) (2,-5) (3,-5) are the nodes and 1-2 and 2-3 i.e 1,2 and 2,3 are connected.Let c be 1, so in this case, we can remove subtree of 2 to maximize weight which would be 1-1*1=0.

I can try to find out the weight of every subtree and delete all those that have weight less than the weight of tree rooted at 1 but this wouldn't be the optimal strategy. I need an O(V) algorithm.

Would appreciate any help determine an optimal algorithm.

Comment: Is this a binary tree?

Comment: It's amazing how inconsistent SO voting can be. Here's the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538119/how-do-i-calculate-the-profit-of-a-given-tree

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem recursively:

- Solve the problem for all the children of the root
- If you chose to discard the whole tree, you get a score of *-C*, if you chose to keep the tree then you should use the optimal solutions for the subtrees which gives you a score of *weight of root + sum of scores of the subtrees*, just take the best of these two.